# No internet connection via my OpenVPN server

Tags: debian, iptables, openvpn, internet, connection

I have OpenVPN up and running on my server. I want all traffic from my clients to be routed trough the VPN server.

The client connects just fine but is unable to connect to the internet.

Server config:

```
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/certs/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/certs/brimstone.crt
key /etc/openvpn/certs/brimstone.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/certs/dh4096.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push redirect-gateway def1
keepalive 10 120
tls-cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA384
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [69770:12550856]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [52469:5225827]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [171:11702]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [136:8184]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [69770:12550856]
:INPUT ACCEPT [69068:12508784]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [684:41112]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [52469:5225827]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [53153:5266939]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
*filter
:INPUT DROP [25:2952]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [320:45993]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 24 07:44:57 2015
```

Did I miss something when configuring the forwarding/routing?

***edit:***

Turns out I made quite a stupid mistake.. I wrote down the iptables rules I need and then forgot one, when actually applying them.

I forgot to allow FORWARDING for established or related sessions..

Comment: can the vpn server connect to the internet?

Comment: yes, the server can access the internet.

Comment: I see you use venet0, so does that mean that this is a VM? have you allowed this traffic in the firewall in VM layer?

Comment: It's a VPS and tun/tap is allowed for the server.

Comment: Please don't use words like 'SOLVED" in question titles. This doesn't mark a question as solved. If the question truly is solved, please post an answer and then mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

several things I can think of,

1) make sure your server is a router, e.g it will forward packages from your clients to other networks.. .this is done like this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or to make this more permanent:

```
pico /etc/sysctl.conf
```

uncomment or add something like this:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

also, does the client get ip address and dns setup? maybe push DHCP over vpn is a good idea

Comment: I had `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` enabled, the tun0 adapter of the client gets the 10.8.0.6, I don't think DNS is tunneled, as I can successfully dig addresses, but can't access anything else.

Comment: do you run the openvpn client with proper rights? (in windows, administrator), so that routing will work?

Comment: I run it as root..

Comment: can you ssh from client to openvpn server? can you confirm that the traffic is routed via vpn on client?

Comment: I can access the server via SSH. How may I confirm that?

Comment: show me the routing table on client `route` or traceroute

Comment: I think I have some problem in the routes.. (route: http://pastebin.com/V2q7msdK) traceroute to some site, goes to 10.8.0.1 but no further..